# Could not handle back/managed reference 'defaultReference'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, angular6

Below code has been modified with @JsonIdentityInfo, still it is not showing the values of Customer Object in the response.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id",scope=FeedbackDetail.class)
```

@Entity
@Table(name="feedback_details")
@NamedQuery(name="FeedbackDetail.findAll", query="SELECT f FROM FeedbackDetail f")
public class FeedbackDetail implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
@Id
//@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="fb_detail_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
private int fbDetailId;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="fb_dur_end_date")
private Date fbDurEndDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="fb_dur_start_date")
private Date fbDurStartDate;

@Column(name="fb_received_date")
private Timestamp fbReceivedDate;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Customer
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="customer_id" , referencedColumnName = "cust_id")  
private Customer customer;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to FinancialYear
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="finyear_id" , referencedColumnName = "finyear_id")    
private FinancialYear financialYear;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Project
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName = "project_id") 
private Project project;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to StatusMaster
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="status_id" , referencedColumnName = "status_id")  
private StatusMaster statusMaster;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Weblink
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="weblink_id", referencedColumnName = "weblink_id") 
private Weblink weblink;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to FeedbackSurvey
@OneToMany(mappedBy="feedbackDetail")
@JsonIgnore
private List<FeedbackSurvey> feedbackSurveys;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to MailReminder
@OneToMany(mappedBy="feedbackDetail")
@JsonIgnore
private List<MailReminder> mailReminders;

public FeedbackDetail() {
}

public int getFbDetailId() {
    return this.fbDetailId;
}

public void setFbDetailId(int fbDetailId) {
    this.fbDetailId = fbDetailId;
}

public Date getFbDurEndDate() {
    return this.fbDurEndDate;
}

public void setFbDurEndDate(Date fbDurEndDate) {
    this.fbDurEndDate = fbDurEndDate;
}

public Date getFbDurStartDate() {
    return this.fbDurStartDate;
}

public void setFbDurStartDate(Date fbDurStartDate) {
    this.fbDurStartDate = fbDurStartDate;
}

public Timestamp getFbReceivedDate() {
    return this.fbReceivedDate;
}

public void setFbReceivedDate(Timestamp fbReceivedDate) {
    this.fbReceivedDate = fbReceivedDate;
}

public Customer getCustomer() {
    return this.customer;
}

public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

public FinancialYear getFinancialYear() {
    return this.financialYear;
}

public void setFinancialYear(FinancialYear financialYear) {
    this.financialYear = financialYear;
}

public Project getProject() {
    return this.project;
}

public void setProject(Project project) {
    this.project = project;
}

public StatusMaster getStatusMaster() {
    return this.statusMaster;
}

public void setStatusMaster(StatusMaster statusMaster) {
    this.statusMaster = statusMaster;
}

public Weblink getWeblink() {
    return this.weblink;
}

public void setWeblink(Weblink weblink) {
    this.weblink = weblink;
}

public List<FeedbackSurvey> getFeedbackSurveys() {
    return this.feedbackSurveys;
}

public void setFeedbackSurveys(List<FeedbackSurvey> feedbackSurveys) {
    this.feedbackSurveys = feedbackSurveys;
}

public FeedbackSurvey addFeedbackSurvey(FeedbackSurvey feedbackSurvey) {
    getFeedbackSurveys().add(feedbackSurvey);
    feedbackSurvey.setFeedbackDetail(this);

    return feedbackSurvey;
}

public FeedbackSurvey removeFeedbackSurvey(FeedbackSurvey feedbackSurvey) {
    getFeedbackSurveys().remove(feedbackSurvey);
    feedbackSurvey.setFeedbackDetail(null);

    return feedbackSurvey;
}

public List<MailReminder> getMailReminders() {
    return this.mailReminders;
}

public void setMailReminders(List<MailReminder> mailReminders) {
    this.mailReminders = mailReminders;
}

public MailReminder addMailReminder(MailReminder mailReminder) {
    getMailReminders().add(mailReminder);
    mailReminder.setFeedbackDetail(this);

    return mailReminder;
}

public MailReminder removeMailReminder(MailReminder mailReminder) {
    getMailReminders().remove(mailReminder);
    mailReminder.setFeedbackDetail(null);

    return mailReminder;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you update the code here?

Comment: It is now working for me.Removed all the annotations and put them one by one as the error occurred for each. @JsonIgnore the parameters which were repeated in the response.